# How to align read to two SHORT reference sequences and see percentage that mapped to one or the other reference?

Tags: bioinformatics, fastq, sequence-alignment

I have PCR-Amplified fastq files of a specific target region from several samples. For each sample, I want to know the percentage of reads that align better to reference sequence #1 or #2 posted below. How should I begin to tackle this question and what tool for alignment is best?

I am working with Illumina paired-end adapter sequences spiked-in on a 2X150 run. The two reference amplicons are 173 and 179 bp:

1: aaaaagtataaatataggaccaggcagagcattttatacaacaggagaaataataggagatataagacaagcacattgtaaccttagtagagcaaaatggaatgacactttaaataagatagttataaaattaagagaacaatttgggaataaaacaatagtctttaagcact

2: aaaaagtatccgtatccagaggggaccagggagagcatttgttacaataggaaaaataggaaatatgagacaagcacattgtaacattagtagagcaaaatggaatgccactttaaaacagatagctagcaaattaagagaacaatttggaaataataaaacaataatctttaagcaat

We want to know if one virus wins over another after infection infection based off of the differences between these two sequences; so essentially the percentage that align best to #1 and the percentage that align best to #2.

Thank You,

Sara

Comment: If you do not get here quickly an answer that you need, try posting the question on [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) or [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/).

Answer (score 0):

- Convert your reference amplicons to `fasta` format.
- Choose an aligner, such as `bwa mem`, `bowtie2`, etc.
- Index the reference for your aligner of choice.
- Align the reads to the reference using your aligner of choice.
- Use `samtools idxstats` to find the number of reads aligned to each of the amplicons.

Notes:

- It is often a good idea to trim adapters from the reads before you align the reads. A number of good adapter trimmers exist, such as `flexbar`, `skewer`, etc.
- Many popular bioinformatics packages mentioned above can be easily installed, for example using `conda`.

**REFERENCES:**

[`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html)
[`bwa`](https://github.com/lh3/bwa)
[`bowtie2`](https://github.com/BenLangmead/bowtie2)
[`samtools`](https://github.com/samtools/samtools)
[`flexbar`](https://github.com/seqan/flexbar)
[`skewer`](https://github.com/relipmoc/skewer)